# How can I connect myself as an other user?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-users, pbkdf2

Hello I am a developper of a django project and I have to check that my dev is okay.

To do this, I have to connect myself as a user but I have just his email not his password. I found in the `table User` this the email and the password but the password begins by this : `pbkdf2_sha256 ...`

So I guess the password is encrypted. Is there a way easier to do this ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: depends what you mean by 'connect as another user'. In general, it's not the idea that you can enter the account of your users, even as admin, that's why there are good protections in place. But it is possible to write code that lets you impersonate other users (e.g. writing a view that switches the current logged in user using the django.contrib.auth `login()` method.). Also it is possible to just `login()` in the django shell (if you have access to that on production). But it's not easy, because it has to done with a lot of care to not introduce security loopholes.

Comment: Normally, if you want to test something in production, create your own non-admin user account and try to duplicate the issue your customer is having.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the passwords are hashed while new users are created, you could just replace the user's hash with another one :

1. Go in database and copy the passwordHash of the user you would like to log with
2. Store this hash somewhere (you will need it to revert the change)
3. Copy the hash of another user (a user for whom you know the password)
4. Paste the hash of this user in place of the hash of the user you want to log in

If the hashs are generated the same way, you will be able to log with the other user's password.

Then when you are done, revert the changes in database.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords in django are one way encrypted so it cannot be decrypted hence there is no way of finding the actual password of any user from the user table in database.
If you want to login on another user's behalf without having to know their password then you can write some complicated code to achieve that, or use a third party package.
[django-hijack](https://github.com/arteria/django-hijack) looks like a good one. Its [docs](http://django-hijack.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) has good explaination on how to use it so I am not going to go through that here. If you don't like this package you can see the list of packages for this purpose [here on djangopackages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/user-switching/) and choose the one you like.

#### django-hijack usage:

Complete the [Installation](https://django-hijack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) and [After Installation](https://django-hijack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#after-installing) steps first.

- Make a post request to `/hijack/<user_id>` where `<user_id>` is the column `id` of table `user`. If you have not updated the field id on model user it will be 1, 2, 3, .... So the url will be similar to `/hijack/1/`
- Make a post request to `/hijack/username/<username>` if you want to hijack by username. eg. `/hijack/username/awesome_username/`
- Make a post request to `/hijack/email/<user email>/` if you want to hijack by email of user. eg. `/hijack/email/awesome@email.com/`

After making a post request to one of these urls as superuser you will be redirected to the specified `HIJACK_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py

---

I am not sure if django-hijack will work on python 3 or newer versions of Django. If it doesn't works try out [django-impersonate](https://bitbucket.org/petersanchez/django-impersonate/src/default/) which provides the same functionality in a similar way and officially supports python 3.6+ and django 1.11+

Comment: I can go to the admin in my website can I log in as an other user with this ?

Comment: django-hijack can work on Python 3.8 and Django 3.

Comment: I am not sure, you will have to test it yourself.